# Should I improve my deleted question, or post a clearer one?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

My [deleted specific-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076615/how-to-make-h1-simulate-p-as-if-h1-is-p-in-css-or-js) has a lot of downvotes and all of the answers to it are unclear because the question is unclear. I'm not sure how what to do next - do I reword that question, or post a new, clearer question since this one's deleted?

For < 10K users:

[image]

Is my new question clearer?

> How apply result of `getComputedStyle` to antoher element without write loop code by myself?

Comment: I'm sorry ,but some people downvotes to my quesetion and I'm beware that indeed need reword so I delete it before more downvotes and (if need) try post a improved question. I think I need some things similar to sandbox.@Makoto

Comment: There is no Sandbox on SO. And for the records: You didn't delete the question yourself. It was delete by three other users.

Comment: I say "delete before more downvotes" is point to just at meta.stackoverflow.com non that specific question. @BDL

Comment: If your deleted question was one sentence, that would explain the down-votes all by itself.

Comment: @theMayer: I edited the post here to add the original question.

Comment: Well, judging by the absence of a "?"  which indicates a question is being asked, I could see why this might be unclear.  But in my opinion, you need a lot more words to explain what it is you're looking for, because what's there isn't going to help anyone get you a solution

Comment: @theMayer:  Let's at least *try* to be more constructive here.  There's a very obvious answer here.  If you're going to broach an answer, then be a bit more earnest about it.

Comment: Of course,I need give you-all a chance to read my question,now I'm can't find out  any unclear.also [I can't find out big difference between my version and you-all version,although my English is very badly.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180577/is-some-ways-find-out-why-english-people-cant-understand-my-mean-my-first-lang) @Makoto

Comment: Now is clearer and meaningful for you? my English is very badly ,but Makoto already reword my quesion. if not,can more prompt information? @theMayer

Comment: as a side note, downvotes on meta are different from the main site .. you should probably take the time to read how all these things works

Answer (score 2):

So I had a chance to think about your question, and the main issue that I see with it is:

...*why* do you want to do this??

The `<h1>` and `<p>` tag serve very specific and very narrow purposes.  Wanting to change all of your header tags to paragraph tags is incredibly suspicious, or wanting of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248).  It's ill-advised to do something like this on any given task without *incredibly* good reason (e.g. you mixed up the tags and now all of your text is header text, which doesn't look that good).

Your clarification isn't clarifying, either, because it doesn't answer the fundamental justification of doing this in the first place.

I would strongly recommend that you explain what your goal is, and why you think moving to paragraph tags in place of header tags would accomplish it.  Chances are, you may solve the issue yourself after thinking through the rationale.

Comment: He *did* explain in his post why he wants to do this (global replace will be too time consuming in his local environment). Whether we as other users judge this reason sufficient to warrant this workaround really isn’t our call. We can certainly suggest it’s not, but the question is still the question.

Comment: @DanBron:  No, that's an explanation as to avoid a specific flavor of this approach.  It doesn't explain why he thinks changing all header tags to paragraph tags is necessary.  There's a significant underlying issue here which isn't being teased out.

Comment: @Makoto  certainly, exact copy computed style from an element to another element is not  necessary for my case(Thank you make me more think,now I'm think out more ways for my case.),but I'm still curious how easy way exact copy computed style from an element to another element,and I think also such question is likely useful and searchable for other people. that new question also is my origin mean,(I'm sorry for my bad express way),so I'm not sure I should just post new question or try continue undelete and reword my old question.